# Question has note about hard-science tag without having the tag itself

Tags: bug

The question below was asked two days ago. It originally had the hard-science tag:

[What would've had to change in the early solar system for Mars to remain habitable?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/104222/21222)

Yesterday the OP made an edition removing the [hard-science](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hard-science) tag. However, the warning about the tag still remains on the question.

> **This question asks for hard science.** All answers to this question should be backed up by equations, empirical evidence, scientific papers, other citations, etc. Answers that do not satisfy this requirement might be removed. See [the tag description](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tags/hard-science/info) for more information.

Is this to be expected? Shouldn't the note go away together with the tag?

Comment: The hard-science notice is added manually by moderators and not automatically by the system; it thus needs to be removed manually as well. I VTC'd this question as a duplicate linking to one of *many* other questions on the meta about the same subject.